# Tough geometry circle triangle

Tags: geometry

> The triangle ABC with an angle of C 30 degrees at the vertex C is inscribed in a circle with a center O and a radius of 9 cm. If R is the radius of the circle tangent to the segments AO and BO, and the arc AB, then R is:?

This is fairly difficult.

Obviously, the circumcenter is $O$ so the perpendicular bisectors are near.

I used: $x = 9\sin(60)$ as an approximate, but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $D,E$ be the tangent point of the small circle and $AO,\text{arc $AB$}$ respectively. Also, let $O'$ be the center of the small circle.

Then, considering the right triangle $OO'D$ gives $OO'=2R$. Now, noting that $O'$ is on the line $OE$ gives that
$$9=OE=OO'+O'E=2R+R$$$$\Rightarrow R=3.$$

Comment: (+1) I cannot get $OO' = 2R$

Comment: @Amad27: Note that $\angle{AOB}=60^\circ$.

Comment: Yes, OO'D is a right triangle with the right angle at $D$. So angle, DOO' = 30$. But how does that give OO' still? OE = 9 = O'E + OO', but I still cannot get OO'?

Comment: @Amad27: We have $DO':OO':OD=1:2:\sqrt 3$.

Comment: @Amad27: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_right_triangles#30.E2.80.9360.E2.80.9390_triangle

Comment: ah I see now, thanks for clearing it up. It is possible however, to do this with trig instead of memorizing 1:2:sqrt(3)?

Comment: @Amad27: Yes, for example, you can use the law of sines, but I do recommend memorizing it.

Answer (score 0):

A sketch can be drawn in which if  $a =9 $ is radius T is tangent length, $R$ is circle radius drawn inside the sector $ABO$ touching $AO,BO, arc AB$ , $ x $ is distance from big circle center to nearest arc point of circle radius $R $,

we need to solve 3 equations:

$$ ( T/R = \sqrt 3 , x*a = T^2, ( x - R)/R =2 ) $$

which has solutions  $$ T = a/ \sqrt 3= 3 \sqrt 3, R = x= a/3 = 3. $$

The circle of radius $R$ and its center *trisect* the center-line.